# Modify an element when an image is loaded using a utility function

Tags: jquery

I want to iterate over a set of `p` elements and add a dynamically created `img` element to each one. When the added image is `load`ed I want to add some text to the `p` element which contains it using a custom utility function called `addText`.

My non working code: (See it in action at http://jsbin.com/abebof/2/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>img { max-width: 100%; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Image #1</p>
    <p>Image #2</p>
    <p>Image #3</p>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

function addText(paragraph, text) {
  paragraph.text(paragraph.text() + '. ' + text);
  console.log('called');
}

$('p').each(function (i) {
  jthis = $(this);
  jthis.css('border', '5px solid');
  addText(jthis, 'The function works!');

  var jimg = $('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/IH38U.png class="loading" />');

  jimg.load(function () {
    addText(jthis, 'Loaded!');
  });
  jimg.appendTo(this);
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Problems with it I'm asking for help with:

1. No image is loaded into the `Image #3` paragraph. Why not?
2. The `Loaded!` message is printed into the `Image #3` paragraph for each image. It should be printed into the paragraph containing the image. How do I rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) for helping me out1 Since I feel his answer can be improved further and stick closer to the original code I provide mine too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>img { max-width: 100%; }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Image #1</p>
    <p>Image #2</p>
    <p>Image #3</p>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

function addText(paragraph, text) {
  paragraph.append(' ' + text); // #1 below
  console.log('called');
}

$('p').each(function (i) {
  jthis = $(this);
  jthis.css('border', '5px solid');
  addText(jthis, 'The function works!');

  var jimg = $('<img class="loading" />'); // #2 below.

  jimg.load(new function () {  // #3 below                  new, it creates a new closure each time.
    addText(jthis, 'Loaded!'); // WORKS now since I added
  });
  jimg.attr("src","http://i.imgur.com/IH38U.png");


  jimg.appendTo(this);
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Explanations of bug fixes in the OP source:

1. `paragraph.text()` retrives the plain text in `paragraph`, filtering out all other DOM nodes. I tried to change simply the text by using `paragraph.text('the new text')` to set simply the text. I was wrong. It effectively sets the plain text and removes everything else which was there. If I think about it that's logical. After all, if it would simply change the text and keep everything else it wouldn't be able to know *where* I wanted the text (ie before or after the img node).
2. The created `img` node starts loading its image as soon as it can. It does not wait until it's included in the DOM. Therefore we must first create it without the image URL, then set the load event function and last set the image URL. If we set the URL immediately it's possible to miss the load event.
3. Everytime a function B is created within a function A a closure is used. The variables in A are accessable from B. The problem is that if many inner functions (Bs) are created they all share the *current* variables in A. To remedy this a new closure is created using `new function`. Confusing? It's for me too. Read the second answer (not the accepted one, it's false) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) for more information.

Comment: Please explain what you improved that warranted a new answer instead of a comment or just an answer without taking away the accept from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the image after you define the load AND use an image you are allowed to show

Lastly you need a closure for jthis! 
I use parent() instead and append instead of replacing the content

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zVGLM/)

```
function addText(paragraph, text) {
  paragraph.append(text);
  console.log('called');
}
$(function() {      
  $('p').each(function (i) {
    jthis = $(this);
    jthis.css('border', '5px solid');
    addText(jthis, 'The function works!');
    var jimg = $('<img />');
    jimg.addClass("loading");
    jimg.on("load",function () {
      addText($(this).parent(), 'Loaded!');
    });
    jimg.appendTo(jthis);
    jimg.attr("src","http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-6.jpg" );

  });
});
```

Comment: "use an image you are allowed to show", Could you elaborate? I thought I'm pretty allowed.

Comment: "You need to add the image after you define the load", am I not doing that? Isn't the jimg.appendTo(this) the statement adding the image?

Comment: Not as far as I know - the var jimg=... could load the image. Anyway, my code works like you need it and is slightly cleaner

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for helping out!